# Asp.net application page hangs/freezes while loading

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajax.net

I have web application using asp.net 3.0 and ajax update panels, web services ... The web page randomly freezes and could not find any error.

Here is a simplified Question: A user select a patient record, the page that shows the patient info ‘freezes’ while loading. CPU usage by the browser is high and stays high, there is no error on the page, and it looks as if it is continuing to load (progress bar never completes). The same user can log into another very similar workstation and access the problem patient record with no issues, and other patients records can be viewed without issues on the original ‘problem’ workstation

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this problem with IE, not sure if that is what the problem workstation is using:

[KB 2000262 - Fix: UpdatePanel Async Postbacks Slow in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000262).

[UpdatePanel Async Postsback slow in IE…Part 3](http://blog.devlpr.net/2009/09/01/updatepanel-async-postsback-slow-in-ie-part-3/)